# Double to integer casting in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, type-conversion

I use *Visual Studio 2010* to write C++ applications. In one of those I do type cast from *double* to *integer* as below:

```
intAmount = (int)doubleAmount;
```

Where `intAmount` is *integer* type and `doubleAmount` is *double* type.

I try to display these and I got an issue when `doubleAmount = 16200000`, it displays as `16199999`
whereas in some other cases I do not face any issues.

For ex: when `doubleAmount = 15400000` or it is `18000000`. These 2 values are displayed correctly.

After some analysis I understood that it's not a proper way of type casting. So I fixed it as below:

```
intAmt = doubleAmount >= 0 ? (int)(doubleAmount+0.5) : (int)(doubleAmount-0.5);
```

The above fix worked well for me.

But **my question is**: why this problem exists only when `doubleAmount = 16200000`.

Can anyone please suggest?

**Edit** Please note that calculation for doubleAmount = 0.81 * 20000000 which equals to 16200000

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Must Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: In `C++11` we have `std::round`. That is more readable as your code. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: floats are approximations of values only.

Comment: if it was  162000001 then it is ok for me i can tell say that precision of double give to that skill but 161999999 just cant be are you sure the code nothing different than you shared here?

Comment: @oknsni: Whatever your comment means, it is not relevant here: you have too many 0's (or 9's). It's 16200000, not 162000000.

Comment: Can you please post a three- or four-line program that shows this behaviour? What you say doesn't quite add up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let me demonstrate that what you claim to be happening is not happening, with a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double doubleAmount = 16200000.0;
    int intAmount = (int)doubleAmount;
    std::cout << intAmount << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
16200000
```

What is happening in your program is that whilst you think that your floating point value is `16200000.0`, in fact it is something like `16199999.xxx`. Your value is most likely coming from some calculation that results in a value close to `16200000.0` but slightly less than `16200000.0`. When you truncate to `int` you get `16199999`.

Why do you think that the value is `16200000.0` when in fact it is a value slightly less? Again I am speculating, but most likely that's because you are not printing the value to full precision. Make sure when you print the value out, or inspect it in the debugger, you are observing the full precision of the value.

This sort of phenomenon is common with floating point calculations. Finite precision binary floating point data types cannot represent all numbers, and cannot perform all calculations exactly. These imprecisions are inherent in binary floating point arithmetic.

Without knowing what problem you are trying to solve, and without knowing how the value was calculated, it is not possible to give you definitive advice on the correct way to tackle your problem. Rounding to the nearest integer (use `std::round` or `std::lround`) may indeed be a reasonably solution to your problem. But without more detail it's not possible to say that with certainty.

Finally, if you have not already done so, it is time to read David Goldberg's classic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: It is not mandatory that such values would come from calculation only, even some literals may have such issue, as numbers stored in log base 2 format.

Comment: @Slava OK, but with probability very close to 1, the issue here is that the value is the result of a calculation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think it does not really matter where that number came from, as root of the problem not in calculations but in the way numbers are represented in floating point format.

Comment: @ DavidHefferna - I am fetching some calculated values(type- double) using our predefined business logic APIs. What i observed is: If i directly do a cout for that double value it dispalys 16200000 but if i typecast to int as mentioned in my post, it displays 16199999. So can you help me here how the floating point value is like 16199999.xxx. If its the case the cout for double also should have printed like 16199999.xxx.Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: When you print the value out, it is not printing the value to full precision. Print the value to full precision and you will see that it is not equal to `16200000.0`.

Comment: @Slava I don't agree. You see, `16200000` is exactly representable. In both single and double precision. So the real issue here is that although the asker thinks that the value if `16200000.0`, the value is in fact, for some reason, slightly less. And in my experience, that almost always comes about because of a calculation that cannot be performed exactly with binary floating point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok..let me put the final calculation result from my API . doubleAmount = 0.81 * 20000000 which equals 16200000.

Comment: If `doubleAmount == 16200000.0` then after `intAmount = (int)doubleAmount;` we have `intAmount == 16200000`. That's trivially easy for you to verify. So, it must be the case that `doubleAmount < 16200000.0`. If you really want to get to the bottom of the specifics then you need to make a complete program to demonstrate what you report.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response..i got my issue. As you pointed out, i was not printing in full precision.The value is slightly less than 16200000 once i tried printing in full precision.So that was the issue.Thanks for valuable suggestion.